# Why thread has an unstable behaviour?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a thread inside a while, but the program works only in some situations. 
I am programming in c++, Boost 1.59 and Visual studio 2012.
Here the code:

```
while(condition){
      boost::thread t(GeneticAlgorithm);
          if(!t.timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(10))){
             //always entry here, because geneticAlgoritm is infinity 
             TerminateThread(t.native_handle(), 0);
             more calculus..
          }
}
```

I wish that after 10 seconds stop the thread and create another thread when returning to "while". The first time I run the thread works, thereafter sometimes works sometimes not. Any idea?

Comment: `TerminateThread` is almost never the right approach.  Ideally you would have some way to interrupt `GeneticAlgorithm`.

Comment: All sources I've ever seen said "don't depend on terminate thread; it will always cause indeterminate program state"

Comment: ^^ queueing tasks to thread pools, good, app-lifetime threads OK, continual create/join/terminate super-suck.

Comment: If you really have to stop stuff and restart, set some 'stopWhenYouCanAndDeleteYourself' boolean in the thread instance, set the priority of the thread to the lowest possible and orphan the thread instance.

Comment: May we see the part of the GeneticAlgorithm where you have your interuptpoints?

Comment: @Surt: I don't have interruption point in GeneticAlgorithm

Comment: What does the return code of TerminateThread say?

Answer (score -1):

No [interruptpoints](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html) no interrupt. The interrupt in here is not a soft or hardware interrupt but a cooperative one.

You will need to add an interrupt point so that the cooperative interrupt can be activated.

> A running thread can be interrupted by invoking the interrupt() member
>   function of the corresponding boost::thread object. When the
>   interrupted thread next executes one of the specified interruption
>   points (or if it is currently blocked whilst executing one) with
>   interruption enabled, then a boost::thread_interrupted exception will
>   be thrown in the interrupted thread. If not caught, this will cause
>   the execution of the interrupted thread to terminate. As with any
>   other exception, the stack will be unwound, and destructors for
>   objects of automatic storage duration will be executed.

You can add an interrupt point this way.

```
bool GeneticAlgorithm() {
    ... some code
    // this point must be passed at least once every 10 sec.
    boost::this_thread::interruption_point(); 
    ... more code
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this earned a downvote. Sure, the only answer to the question is "Don't do that." but at least this is an attempt at providing an alternative.

Comment: Actually I was trying to say "you need to add an interrupt point", I'll better write that in the answer.

Comment: That's what I read from it, but using a bigger hammer to drive the point home rarely hurts.